# MySQL Hibernate Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm kinda confused what's wrong here. I'm new at using hiberate.

I want to get a list where I can get an ID and Role at the same time

Here's my pojo

**Users.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name= "users")
public class Users implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String gender;
    private String username;
    private String birthDate;
    private String address;
    private String contactNo;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<BusinessHandled> businessHandled;


    public Users(){

    }
    public Users(Users user) {
        this.userId = user.userId;
        this.username = user.username;
        this.emailAddress = user.emailAddress;
        this.password = user.password;
        this.gender=user.gender;
        this.firstName=user.firstName;
        this.middleName=user.middleName;
        this.lastName=user.lastName;
        this.birthDate=user.birthDate;
        this.address=user.address;
        this.contactNo=user.contactNo;
        this.businessHandled = user.businessHandled;

    }




}
```

here's my 
**BusinessHandled.java**

```
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

public class BusinessHandled {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="business_id")
    private Business business;
    private String role;

    public Business getBusiness() {
        return business;
    }

    public void setBusiness(Business business) {
        this.business = business;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }



}
```

while here's my 
**Business.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Business  {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long businessId;
    String businessName;




    Business(){
        super();
    }

    public Business(Long businessId, String businessName, String businessOwner, String username, String role){
        this.businessId = businessId;
        this.businessName = businessName;
    }






}
```

I've checked some other questions here and suggested that I use persistence and I did but I somehow I can't make it work

anyone knows the problem? stuck here for hours

Comment: *stuck here for hours* but you didn't described the issue

Comment: i see a lot of confusion. my suggestion is to start from the basic of a mapping tutorial

Comment: the error is in the title

Comment: The error states exactly the problem. What you *can* do: make `BusinessHandled` an entity; or make `BusinessHandled` an `@Embeddable` and modify the annotations on the field, i.e. make it an `@ElementCollection` first of all.